# Functional Javascript BaconJS, how can I push more values to an event stream?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, functional-programming, bacon.js

I'm attempting to create a stack of AJAX responses in BaconJS. That processes them in a first in first out fashion, but each 'out' event should wait for user input.

This is where I'm at now: [Live JSBin](http://jsbin.com/qiyara/1/edit?html,js,console,output)

```
var pages = Bacon.fromArray([1,2,3])
var next = $("#next").asEventStream('click').map(true);

pages.flatMapConcat(asyncFunction).zip(next).log("responses")

function asyncFunction(page) {
  // Simulating something like an AJAX request
  return Bacon.later(1000 + (Math.random() * 3000), "Page "+ page)
}
```

Currently this synchronously outputs an event from the `pages` `EventStream` each time that `#next` is clicked, which the behavior I want.

---

**However**, I am unable to figure out how to push more values to the `pages` `EventStream`. I have attempted to replace the pages EventStream with a `Bus`, and pushing values like this (which doesn't work).

```
var pages = new Bacon.Bus()
pages.push("value")
```

---

How do I push more values to an `EventStream`?

Comment: Why not just use the parameter object pattern?

Comment: Can you give an example of how that will help solve my problem?

Comment: Where are the values that you want to push coming from?

Comment: Well you can't "push" to an EventStrean unless it's a bus. You can, however, gather events from different sources into the same stream using `merge` for example. But as Bergi asked, where do your "more values" come from. Can you add them to your example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is an OLD post, but bus would work.  Just push the number (you had an array of numbers before) into it:

```
var pages = new Bacon.Bus();
// Bacon.fromArray([1,2,3])
var next = $("#next").asEventStream('click').map(true);

pages.flatMapConcat(asyncFunction).zip(next).log("responses")

function asyncFunction(page) {
  // Simulating something like an AJAX request
  return Bacon.later(1000 + (Math.random() * 3000), "Page "+ page)
}


pages.push(1);
pages.push(2);
pages.push(3);
```

[I cloned your jsbin and changed it to use bus](http://jsbin.com/rukaqa/edit?js,console)

As mentioned previously, you could stream the source of the page values using something like [fromEvent](https://baconjs.github.io/api.html#bacon-fromevent) or from [fromBinder](https://baconjs.github.io/api.html#baconfrombinder-for-custom-streams)